# Laravel 4 blade template won't render whole page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm running into a weird issue where my page isnt' getting rendered in its entirety. The bottom bit is getting cut off and I'm not sure why.

I'd paste code, but it's a 3000+ line template im trying to implement.

I am doing it as follows in dashboard.master:

```
@include('dashboard.master.head')
...
@include('dashboard.master.header')
...
@include('dashboard.master.sidebar')
...
@include('dashboard.master.style_customizer')
...
@include('dashboard.master.page_header')
...
@yield('content')
...tons of lines here
```

It renders up to content correctly, and awhile after that but it seems to stop at some point.

example of my blade file calling my master

```
@extends('dashboard.master')
@section('content')
    <p>This is my content</p>
@stop
```

Edit:
I tried removing everything and just pasting the HTML template I have. It still just stops rendering towards the end of the page. So all I have now is literally the master file and the includes in my blade template that calls the master.

Comment: My template is ~4.5K lines of code. Could this be the issue that its simply too long?

Comment: It doesn't sound like it, but are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Another option that you have is to clear out the `{application}/app/storage/views` folder, then refresh the one page that has that. Check that folder again, you'll see a view. Cat that out, see if there's anything wrong

Comment: There are no errors its simply just not rendering code. Ill take a look at your suggestion ChrisForrence

Comment: @ChrisForrence are you saying I should delete everything in my views folder?

Comment: Almost. There's app/storage/views, and app/views. app/storage/views is a cache of the views accessed by the application (with filenames like "55d8270d0c946ca4eb922298fd1f4b27" or "a3a01557e108f13b1491b1bc546a0ac4". Delete the files in _that_ folder.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Great, thank you! It seems to have fixed my issue. Was driving me INSANE. Could you please explain to me why this happens so I can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel will maintain a cache of views that have been accessed, just so that it doesn't have to compile the blade template for each page load. It should be refreshing a particular view should it change, but it sounds like, for some reason, the cache wasn't being refreshed.

You can clear the view cache in two different ways:

```
# Method 1
php artisan cache:clear

# Method 2
rm `ls /path/to/application/app/storage/views | grep -v '.gitignore'`
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23412018/899126)

Answer (score 0):

In order to show all page, change your last code to :

```
@extends('dashboard.master')
@section('content')
    <p>This is my content</p>
@show
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Still same issue. I literally took out ALL the blade code, copy+pasted my template and it still stops rendering half-way through.